# Prove a set in dense in R

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Fix and arbitrary $r$ such that $0 < r < 1$.

Define the set **T** = {$kr^n$ : $k$ is an integer and $n$ is a natural number}

Prove that **T** is dense in **R**

Comment: HINT: The sequence $\langle r^n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ converges to $0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $x\in\Bbb R$.  Let $\epsilon>0$.  Since $r^n\rightarrow0$, we can choose $n\in\Bbb N$ such that $r^n<\epsilon$.  Then the integer multiples of $r^n$ create an evenly spaced set of real numbers each less than $\epsilon$ from its neighbor.  So there will be one within $\epsilon$ of $x$.

Comment: This problem was much easier than I originally thought. I was able to figure it out immediately after seeing this...Thank you!

Comment: @Adiea You're welcome.  Please hit that little check mark on at least one answer, to mark the answer as accepted.  Thank you :-)

Answer (score 2):

To show that $\mathbf{T}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$, it suffices to show that for each $x$ in $\mathbb{R}$, there exists a sequence $\{x_{n}\}\subset\mathbf{T}$ such that $x_{n}\rightarrow x$.

Let $x$ be arbitrary. Define $x_{n}= k_{n}r^{n}$ where $k_{n}$ satisfies $$|x-k_{n}r^{n}|=\min_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}|x-kr^{n}|.$$ Can you prove $x_{n}\rightarrow x$?